# Calculating the smallest remainder from variable maximum number of 2 items combined in 4 ratios

Tags: excel, math, logic

This will be done in excel but, I am mostly just looking for the math/logic, although code is appreciated :)

I have 4 items. Let's label them i1 through i4. These 4 items can be made by combining Materials matA and matB in different ratios:

i1 requires 8 matA and 2 matB
i2 requires 6 matA and 4 matB
i3 requires 4 matA and 6 matB
i4 requires 2 matA and 8 matB

With variable amounts of matA and variable amounts of matB, how can I calculate the combination of multiple items to make which would use the absolute maximum amount of matA and matB available (leaving the lowest remainder of both items)?

I feel like there is something really simple here that I'm missing, but I'm confused. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you described is the logic and math....what you looking for is a formula. Have you tried anything? If so, add it to your question, you might be close.

Comment: "Maximum amount of matA and matB"? You mean the maximum of the sum, or what? If you can define it more clearly, you'll probably have one of [the Knapsack Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems).

Comment: yes in essence I'm looking for the highest number of used material, or lowest remainder of material after combining. I am not familiar with many formulas, and this isn't homework! It does seem like it may be a Knapsack problem although I'm having a tough time seeing one that fits this specific variation possibly.

Comment: Actually I think I got it, seems to be the set-union knapsack problem.